# .env File With WebApplicationFactory

Tags: .net-core, integration-testing, connection-string

I am setting up integration tests for my company. Each developer is going to have their own "integration-test" db. My goal is to put a connection string into a .env file and throw that file into the .gitignore so these changes are kept out of source control.
When I try to access the contents of the .env file from my WebApplicationFactory the variables are empty. Any ideas why this is?
I'll paste the code, let me know if there is anything I can clarify

```
public class ApiWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        DotNetEnv.Env.Load();
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseSerilog()
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(x => { x.UseStartup<Startup>().UseTestServer(); });
        return builder;
    }
    
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        var devDb = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONN");
        builder.UseEnvironment("IntegrationTest");
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONN",
            devDb);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "IntegrationTest");
        // Is be called after the `ConfigureServices` from the Startup
        // which allows you to overwrite the DI with mocked instances
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
          {
              services.AddAuthentication("IntegrationTest")
                  .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, IntegrationTestAuthenticationHandler>("IntegrationTest",
                      options => { }
                  );
          });
    }
}
```

var devDb in ConfigureWebHost is null, why isn't it being populated?!

Comment: Have you verified CreateHostBuilder is being called?  If it's not, then it's likely you want to override/implement CreateWebHostBuilder instead.

Comment: Yes, CreateHostBuilder is being called, verified by debugging and setting a breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create custom appsettings file to use for your test environment `appsettings.test.json` and set the connection string.

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DB_CONN": "Data Source...."
  }
}
```

Set `IConfiguration` to read the json file in `WebApplicationFactory.CreateHostBuilder()`

```
 Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsetting.test.json")
                .Build();
```

If your system is using `appsettings` then you can add it when creating the host.

For setting environment variables based on the Configuration, you can manually set the variables in `ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)`

```
 Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONN", Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB_CONN"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you should use `appsetting.json` and add connections string, logging configurations etc. configs to this file. Don't use environment values for connection strings or other application level configs. You can generate `appsettings.Development.json`,`appsettings.Stage.json`,`appsettings.Production.json` for different platforms. After making that, when you change your `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment value to `Development`, .NET will read values (connection string, log configs etc.) from `appsettings.Development.json` automatically. After these steps, you can add `appsettings` json file which you want to kept out of source control.